# How to solve "IndexError at / list index out of range" when there is an empty list

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I was wondering what the simplest way is to return null in Django when there is an empty list coming from an API "leverage_buy": [],:

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from meal_app.models import Kraken
import requests

def get_krakens(request):
    all_krakens = {}
    url ='https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs' 
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    for i in data['result'].values():
        kraken_data = Kraken(
            altname = i['altname'], 
            leverage_buy = i['leverage_buy'][0],
            )
        kraken_data.save()
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Kraken(models.Model):
    altname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True, null = True)
    leverage_buy = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Postman response

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "1INCHEUR": {
            "altname": "1INCHEUR",
            "leverage_buy": [],
```

I researched and tried thoroughly many similar cases here, but none had the example of an API empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a ternary operator:

```
for i in data['result'].values():
    kraken_data = Kraken.objects.create(
        altname = i['altname'], 
        leverage_buy = i['leverage_buy'][0] if i['leverage_buy'] else None
    )
```